# JQuery Filtering with Radio Buttons in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to filter events with a set of buttons in the JQUERY FullCalendar.

I got it working with a dropdown, where you select the dropdown and it filters events based on if the category is dog or cat. But I cant get it to do it with normal buttons.

Dropdown working:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
// page is now ready, initialize the calendar..
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  displayEventTime: false,
  themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
    header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
          },
          editable: false, // Don't allow editing of events
          handleWindowResize: true,

          //console.log((events))

         events : [{start: '7/17/2018',title:"Single Type", category:"Dog"},
         {start: '7/19/2018',title:"Single Type", category:"Cat"},
         {start: '7/23/2018',title:"Multiple Types", category:"Cat, Dog"},
         {start: '7/26/2018',title:"Multiple Type", category:"Dog, Cat"},],          /**/

   eventRender: function(event, element,view) {
            element.qtip({
                content: event.description + '<br />',
                style: {
                   classes: 'qtip-green',
                },
                position: {
                    corner: {
                        target: 'center',
                        tooltip: 'bottomMiddle'
                    }
                }
                })
                         return $('#type_selector').val() === 'all' || event.category.indexOf($('#type_selector').val()) >= 0;
                 },

      });
      $('#type_selector').on('change',function(){
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');});



    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>


    <select id="type_selector">
      <option value="all">all</option>
      <option value="Dog">Dog </option>
      <option value="Cat">Cat </option>
     <select>
     <div id="calendar"></div>
```

One thing that worked for me was adding radio buttons,  which would successfully render the calendar. But the buttons do not work, they are not filtering the events.

Replace the return to:

```
return $('input[type=radio][name=type_selector]').val() === 'all' || event.category.indexOf($("input[type=radio][name=type_selector]:checked").val()) >= 0;
```

and replace JQuery with

```
 $('#type_selector input[type=radio]').on('change',function(){
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');});
```

buttons html:

```
    <input type="radio" name="type_selector" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="all" id="all" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="type_selector" value="Dog"id="Dog">
    <input type="radio" name="type_selector" value="Cat"id="Cat">
```

Comment: "I cant get it to do it with normal buttons."...I can't see any attempt to do that. Have you tried? What happens when you try? We can't fix code we can't see, and have no problem description for. Not sure why you think buttons is a good UX for this though? How about radio buttons or checkboxes, would make more sense (depending if you want to allow multiple items to be selected at once, or not)?

Comment: I added my attempt when I was fiddling around with radio buttons. And you are right, radio buttons would work better.

Comment: Ok...so is there still a problem you want us to help with, or not?

Comment: Yes,there is. The other buttons dont work. It's not functioning, and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited you snippet. Your onchange should look like this because you don't have the id #type_selector anymore in your radio.

```
$('input[type=radio][name=type_selector]').on('change',function(){
       console.log("Event");
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');});
```

In your return statement you should use the :checked Option to get the current selected radio value.

```
$('input[type=radio][name=type_selector]:checked').val() === 'all' || event.category.indexOf($("input[type=radio][name=type_selector]:checked").val()) >= 0;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
// page is now ready, initialize the calendar..
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  displayEventTime: false,
  themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
    header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
          },
          editable: false, // Don't allow editing of events
          handleWindowResize: true,

          //console.log((events))

         events : [{start: '7/17/2018',title:"Single Type", category:"Dog"},
         {start: '7/19/2018',title:"Single Type", category:"Cat"},
         {start: '7/23/2018',title:"Multiple Types", category:"Cat, Dog"},
         {start: '7/26/2018',title:"Multiple Type", category:"Dog, Cat"},],          /**/

   eventRender: function(event, element,view) {
            element.qtip({
                content: event.description + '<br />',
                style: {
                   classes: 'qtip-green',
                },
                position: {
                    corner: {
                        target: 'center',
                        tooltip: 'bottomMiddle'
                    }
                }
                })
                         
                         var ret = $('input[type=radio][name=type_selector]:checked').val() === 'all' || event.category.indexOf($("input[type=radio][name=type_selector]:checked").val()) >= 0;
                         console.log($('input[type=radio][name=type_selector]:checked').val());
return ret;
                 },

      });
       $('input[type=radio][name=type_selector]').on('change',function(){
       console.log("Event");
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');});



    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>


     <input type="radio" name="type_selector" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="all" id="all" checked> all
    <input type="radio" name="type_selector" value="Dog" id="Dog">Dog
    <input type="radio" name="type_selector" value="Cat"id="Cat">Cat
     <div id="calendar"></div>
```

I hope this helps.